# how to push to a new page using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, and I am trying to push to a new page... here's what I have.

```
export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (user == null) {
    this.props.history.push(routes.CLIENTS)
  }
```

how to I declare this.props, or how do I actually push the new page? It is logging error:

```
'props' is not defined      no-undef
```

here is my entire `createCheckoutSession` function.

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const app = firebase.app();


// var userID = "";
// firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
//   if(user) {
//     userID = user.uid
//     console.log(user.uid)
// }
// });



    export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
      if (user == null) {
        this.props.history.push(routes.CLIENTS)
      }
    
      console.log(user)
    
      //price ID with trial LIVE ID
      var price = 'price_1IGW85KDPaWWeL1yjWsi9oRa'
    
      // var price = 'price_1Iav0JKDPaWWeL1yBa9F7Aht'
    
     firestore.collection('customers').doc(user.uid).collection('subscriptions').get().
     
      if (activtyStatus == "canceled") {
        console.log("sub is cancelled")
        //live price
        price = 'price_1IfmDsKDPaWWeL1ywjMTGarh'
        
      
      }
      
      console.log("activity status is: " + activtyStatus)
    
     
    
    
          const checkoutSessionRef = await firestore
          .collection('customers')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('checkout_sessions')
          .add({
            price: price,
            success_url: "http://localhost:3000/clients",
            cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/signin",
        });
    
        
          // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
                checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(function (snap) {
                  const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
                  if (error) {
               
                  console.log(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
                  return;
                }
                if (sessionId) {
                 
    
                
                
                const stripe = window.Stripe('pk');
                console.log("going to stripe: ")
                // this.setState({ isRegistering: true });
               
               console.log("line 116 checkout.js")
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: sessionId})
                console.log("logged stripe")
                
              }
          });
        }
```

it is basically a function to call stripe, and open the stripe checkout page in the new window. So I am trying to catch if the `user == null`, and if true, the push them to sign in page

here is how I am calling the function:

```
if (regData == "yes") {
        console.log("INSIDE broom spinner" + regData)
    
        createCheckoutSession(user.uid)
    
      }
```

Comment: `createCheckoutSession` is not a class, so `this.props` is undefined. May you share a [mcve] of how `createCheckoutSession` is used?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `createCheckoutSession` just redirects to stripe. is there a way to define `props`?

Comment: Depending on how it is used, the props would likely be where `activitStatus` currently is defined. Are you familiar with function components?

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh okay. I am passing through `activityStatus` as a parameter when I am calling the function from the another page, so I don' know if I could declare them in there. and no I am not familiar with function components.

Comment: If you're calling the function then it is not a component, which means it has no props. I'm also not convinced an async function can be used as a component

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh I see, okay. So is there a way inside the function to call to push to a page?

Comment: Please may you add more information to the example? What is `props.history`? Consider making a [mcve] that we can look at and maybe run?

Comment: Please may you add the react code? Where this function is used?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am actually only calling this function through javascript. I have attached an example to my question above